# How to populate an ODS table to bring the newly generated IDs from other tables

Tags: database, ssis, etl

Im creating an ODS layer that has 4 tables as follows

Location
LocationID   (identity column to generate new IDs for location)
LocationState
LocationCity

CompanyTable
CompanyID
CompanyName
CompanyRevenueHigh
CompanyRevenueLow

DepartmentTable
DepartmentID
DepartmentName
DepartmentRevenue

MainTableODS
(has all the above mentioned columns including the ID columns)

My question is that after I populated the (Location ,CompanyTable ,DepartmentTable )
and the identity seed generated the new IDs, how can I populate the main table (MainTableODS) and keep the same integrity because some rows for example the company name can have up to 20 different rows and each one has a different ID
so how can I make sure everything will be aligned correctly in the main table

I'm using SQL server 2012 and SSIS

Comment: Hi - please can you explain what the purpose is of the MainTableODS, why are you combining 3 tables into 1? Also, what is the structure of this table and what do you mean by "aligned correctly"? Please can you provide some sample data that illustrates the usage you are facing?

Comment: Sorry, I meant issue not usage towards the end of the last sentence